# Centralised configuration management for basic linksys routers?

Tags: linksys, configuration-management, router, firmware

Does anyone know if its possible to install a custom router firmware, such as dd-wrt and then use a central config management tool to push/pull changes? The setup here involves each office having their own router, and as the 'ISP' we need to control/maintain router config. Just wondered if its been done before?

Answer (score 1):

I have several WRT54GL routers that I have flashed dd-wrt v24-sp2 onto. The majority of the settings on these routers are identical as they are all performing the same functions.

I manage these devices over the WAN link via ssh. I have wrote a script to log into a list of routers via my ssh settings. The script will update each router with a list of nvram settings

for example:

> nvram set log_enable=1
>
> nvram set log_dropped=1
>
> nvram set log_rejected=1
>
> nvram set lan_proto=static
>
> nvram set wl_radio=0
>
> nvram commit
>
> reboot

You should also be able to perform an NVRAM show and record that information for a backup configuration

Another option with ddwrt might be SNMP if you are familer with that. I have not tried using it with ddwrt devices, but have heard from others that it is supported.